# ¿Cómo no perder el alcance en un exec() de mongoose?

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

Tengo una función que tiene que retornar un array de usuarios, pero al hacer la consulta y retornar el array, este me retorna `undefined` por que esta perdiendo el alcance.

```
function descartUsers(_id: string){
  Usuario.findById(_id)
    .populate({path: 'seguidos'})
    .exec(function (err, result: any){
      const exclude = [ _id ]
      for (let i = 0; i < result.seguidos.length; i++) {
        exclude.push(result.seguidos[i]._id)
      }
      return exclude
    })
}
```

Esta función me retorna `undefined` e intento que retorne la constante `exclude`

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea obtener el resultado de un proceso asíncrono y que el mismo sea devuelto en una sentencia `return` de una función.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para poder obtener el resultado de un proceso asíncrono necesitas manejar el mismo como lo que es: un proceso asíncrono.

Los procesos asíncronos en Javascript se caracterizan por ser procesos no bloqueantes, es decir que el programa no debe esperar que los mismos terminen de ejecutarse para seguir funcionando. Es por ello que una llamada a un proceso asíncrono simplemente enviará el mismo a la **fila de eventos** y continuará la ejecución de la siguiente línea de código. Cuando el proceso asíncrono finalice, el resultado estará disponible, y el **ciclo de eventos** podrá colocar el mismo en la **pila de llamadas** para ser usado por nuestra aplicación. Más o menos es así como funciona un proceso asíncrono en una aplicación JS.

En principio parece algo confuso, pero en realidad lo puedes hacer de diferentes formas, una vez que entiendes cómo funciona. Sin embargo, debes tomar en cuenta que el resultado de un proceso asíncrono no estará disponible inmediatamente y tampoco lo podrás usar directamente en el entorno global. Es allí donde entra en escena el uso de Promesas y funciones tipo `async` junto con la sentencia `await`.

**Usando una función `callback`**

Podrías escribir tu función de tal forma que reciba como argumento una función `callback`, y ejecutar las acciones dentro de la misma. Tal como las ejecutas dentro de la función `callback` que pasas como argumento al método `exec()`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// la siguiente función recibe como argumento una función callback (cb)
function descartUsers(_id: string, cb){
  // verificamos que cb sea una función, si no lo es, retornamos undefined
  if(!cb || Object.prototype.toString.call(cb) !== "[object Function]" ||
     typeof cb !== "function" || !(cb instanceof Function)) return;

  Usuario.findById(_id)
    .populate({path: 'seguidos'})
    .exec(cb) // <- Pasamos la función cb como argumento de exec()
}

//ahora usamos la función antes declarada:

descartUsers(id, function (err: any, result: any){
  if(err) {
    // acciones de manejo de error
  }
  const exclude = [ _id ]
  for (let i = 0; i < result.seguidos.length; i++) {
    exclude.push(result.seguidos[i]._id)
  }
  // aquí puedes usar la variable exclude
});
```

Como se ve en el código, sólo tendré acceso a la variable `exclude` dentro de mi función `callback`, por lo tanto no hemos ganado mucho. No puedo devolver un valor desde mi función `callback` directamente a una variable, porque la ejecución de esta función se realizará cuando el proceso asíncrono definido por el método `find()` finalice, y no tengo certeza de cuando eso ocurrirá.

**Usando `async / await`**

Podemos definir la función como una función tipo `async` y utilizar la sentencia `await` para recibir el resultado en una variable directamente. El método `find()` devuelve una Promesa, por lo tanto debemos utilizar un bloque `try/catch` para trabajar con ella.

Podríamos hacerlo así:

```js
async function descartUsers(_id: string){
  try {
    let exlcude = [ _id ];
    let result: any = Usuario.findById(_id).populate({path: 'seguidos'}).exec();
    result.seguidos.forEach(seguido: any => {
      exclude.push(seguido._id);
    }
    // ya tengo los valores en exclude, puedo trabajar con ellos
  } catch (e: any) {
    // manejo de la excepción
  }
}
```

En el código se aprecia que puedo trabajar con los resultados una vez obtenidos, pero solo dentro de la función tipo `async`.

Si deseo trabajar con ellos fuera de mi función `async`, tendría que usar los métodos `then()` y `catch()`, ya que toda función tipo `async` devuelve una Promesa, ergo, implementa `then()` y `catch()`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// función tipo async devuelve una Promesa
async function descartUsers(_id: string){
  try {
    let exlcude = [ _id ];
    let result: any = Usuario.findById(_id).populate({path: 'seguidos'}).exec();
    result.seguidos.forEach(seguido: any => {
      exclude.push(seguido._id);
    }
    return exclude; // <- devuelvo la variable para ser usada en el método then()
  } catch (e: any) {
    throw(e) // <- lanzo el error para ser usado en el método catch()
  }
}

// Ahora invoco a mi función
descartUsers(id)
.then(exclude: any => {
  // aquí puedo trabajar con el valor de la Promesa una vez que la misma se completa
})
.catch(e: any => {
  // aquí manejo una posible excepción
});
```

Como puedes observar, seguimos sin poder usar la variable directamente en el entorno desde que es llamada nuestra función, por lo tanto aún usando `async/await` tenemos que escribir la lógica de nuestro programa dentro del método `then()` que implementa nuestra Promesa.

**Crear un entorno `async`**

Podemos ir más allá y crear un entorno tipo `async` que se autoejecute o, si nuestro entorno no es el global sino una función, podemos declarar dicha función como `async`. Esto con el propósito de poder usar la sentencia `await` sobre nuestra Promesa.

Supongamos que tu entorno es de una función, digamos un `middleware` de Express, por ejemplo. El código podría verse así:

```js
// la declaración de la función:
async function descartUsers(_id: string){
  try {
    let exlcude = [ _id ];
    let result: any = Usuario.findById(_id).populate({path: 'seguidos'}).exec();
    result.seguidos.forEach(seguido => {
      exclude.push(seguido._id);
    }
    return exclude; // <- devuelvo la variable para ser usada en el método then()
  } catch (e: any) {
    throw(e) // <- lanzo el error para ser usado en el método catch()
  }
}

// el middleware para la ruta
app.use('/ruta', async (req: any, res: any) => { // aquí declaro una función flecha tipo async
  let id: string = req.body._id; // me lo invento que da allí sacas el valor.
  // no olvidar que al trabajar con Promesas debo usar try/catch
  try {
    let exclude: any = await descartUsers(id);
    // trabajo con el valor de exclude
  } catch(e: any) {
    // manejo de errores
  }
});
```

De esta forma ya podrías trabajar directamente y de forma "aparentemente" sincrónica con el resultado del método `find()`. Digo aparentemente, porque no es sincrónico, solo aparenta serlo por la forma en la que está escrito.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.